# How to write requests and fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, get, fetch

I need help how to correctly write a GET and POST request in my server (*index.js*) and how to properly write the fetch in *App.js*.

I have read threads here on Stackoverflow and I have searched for information on how to write requests and fetches but I find it very difficult how to add the examples to my own code. I have tried different solutions for three weeks but getting nowhere it feels like. So, please help. I feel like this should not be that difficult, but for some reason  it is. I have no one to ask for help other than here.

I'm using the URL http://localhost:8080/reviews

Is this how I write or do I have to add anything? (in Index.js)

```
app.get("/reviews", (request, response) => {
    response.status(201).json
  });

 app.post('/reviews', async (request, response) => {
    response.status(201).json
  });
```

In App.js I want to create a fetch where I GET all the existing reviews that are written (none at the moment since the page isn't done yet) and I want to be able to POST new reviews. When I post a new review I want the page to load and update with the new and all the other written reviews.

I have something like this at the moment, but I don't know what the last parts should be?

```
const reviewsURL = "http://localhost:8080/reviews"

export const App = () => {
  const [existingReviews, setExistingReviews] = useState([])
  const [newReview, setNewReview] = useState('')


  const fetchReviews = () => {
    fetch(reviewsURL, {'

    // WHAT ELSE TO WRITE HERE ???

     useEffect(() => {
    fetchReviews();
  }, []);


const postReview = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch(reviewsURL, {
      method: 'POST',
    
     // WHAT DO I WRITE HERE ???
 
  }
  return (
    <>

<NewReview
      newReview={newReview}
      setNewReview={setNewReview}
      handlesubmit={postReview}
      />

{<AllReviews 
        allReviews={existingReviews} 
        />}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: `app.get("/reviews"` - is your server side on Express.js? Or some other framework / library?

Comment: @TKoL I'm using Node / Express. This will only be local, I will not upload this to another page other than GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

In express.js, `response.status(201).json` is not the way to return a JSON response. `.json` is a function, so you would pass it a JSON-ifiable object, `response.status(201).json(resultsArray);` or something like that.

A lot of people prefer to use a library for making requests, rather than using `fetch`. Axios is a common favourite, and lots of people find it much easier to use.

If you'd prefer to use `fetch` over an easier library, that's fine, fetch is still simple enough to get going with. [Here's some documentation on how to use fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Of note: the `fetch(url)` function returns a promise, so you'll either `.then` the returned promise, or `await` it inside an async function. If you're expecting a JSON response, the patterns in the example code in the docs require an extra step to get the content:

```
const result = await fetch(url);
const data = await result.json();
```

That's for a GET request, but the docs also show how to get going with POST requests.